# where should i start if i want to make an enemy from robots forever 2 (or if you are unfamiliar a physics based enemy that uses procedural generation)

Tags: unity, physics, animation, ai

this is probably a long shot, but I didn't really know where to ask this question. I just wanted to ask if anyone knows any resources that can help explain how to make something like this.
Thanks, and sorry for the trouble

I've seen videos on procedural animation, but all the ones I've found have been a floating body with legs that connect to the ground as its moves which makes a walking animation, though these are not affected by physics, so I'm not that interested.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the ML Agents from Unity? They have a demo for a crawler, teaching it how to walk, if that is what you want: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/develop/docs/Learning-Environment-Examples.md#crawler

Comment: Please edit your question to include a description, images, diagrams, or animations to explain what this enemy does that you want to imitate. This helps you get answers even from users who don't know Robots Forever 2 off the top of their heads, so you get useful answers faster.

Comment: @Zibelas yes wow that's perfect thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to simulate the movement of a robot completely using physics. You need to make the robot stand, move, and turn in balance, and all this can only be done through the control of a limited number of joints. But good thing the bots are in the game world, we can easily cheat.

Here is an example from The Legend of Zelda:

[image]

The robot in the picture uses several single-function components to realize the stable walking of the biped robot.

First it uses a component that provides torque to keep the robot in balance:

[image]

It then makes the robot's two feet cycle out of phase. If the robot has more legs, you can refer to the movement patterns of animals or insects:

[image]

In conclusion, the solution is:

1. Artificially providing torque to the robot's torso to give it a tendency to maintain balance.
2. Similarly, add a y-torque to the robot's torso to make it rotate toward the target.
3. Use the animation system or timeline to control all the legs so they have an animation sequence that moves forward.
4. Adjust the gravity of the torso, when the number of remaining legs of the robot reaches a threshold, the robot falls.